# IS there any ways TfidfVectorizer to NER tagging?

Tags: nlp, tf-idf

I have a code like this. Is there any way ner tagging with this vectorizer?
Or to put other tokenizer on this model?

```py
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text 
import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words=stop_words)
```

I asked chat-gpt but what it suggested doesn't work.